# Network science: How to calculate assortativity (Pearson's correlation) coefficient for this small network?

Tags: correlation, graph-theory, networks

Let $A$ denote a weighted, directed network, where the weights in the rows are the out-degrees, and weights in the columns are the in-degrees:

$A$ = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}

[image: Plot:]

Here is the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assortativity#Assortativity_coefficient) that I would like to use (the notation isn't clear to me):

$$r= \frac{\sum_{jk}(jk(e(j,k)-q(j)q(k)))}{\sigma_{q}^2}$$

According to my R function (igraph), $r = - 0.5$
.

My problem is that I don't understand what the variables denote in this formula. I read the book Networks by Newman, and it provided the same 'minimalist' information about the equation.

I tried to calculate the correlation by links or by the sum of the in- and out-degrees of the nodes, however, my results were different. Let $x$ be the vector of out-edges, and $y$ the vector of in-edges:
$x=(1,1,0), y=(0,0,2)$, then $corr(x,y)=-1$.

Could someone show me a step-by-step solution, please?